# value of Bool in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The value of BOOL in objective C is always NO(by default). But recently I encountered a case where the value of BOOL variable was returning YES (by default). Can anybody explain this to me ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`BOOL` has no value as it is a type.

You probably mean variables of type BOOL. There are different types of variables, which have different initialization semantics:

1. **Instance variables**: Objective-C's `alloc` promises to set all instance variables to zero, which in case of BOOL means `NO`;
2. **Global variables**: Or, more precisely, variables with static storage duration are initialized to zero, as defined in the C standard.
3. **Local variables** are not initialized. If you don't assign a value, their contents are unspecified. This is also from the C standard and probably what you stumbled upon.

Comment: #3 is what I was going to post as well!

Comment: Does that mean that int a will NOT always give value 0 in Objective C ?

Comment: @Mindfreak: exactly. All local (function scope) variables always have to be initialized.

Comment: +1 for point 3 which is almost certainly the problem underlying the questioner's question.

Comment: @Mindfreak - In fact, I believe the latest version of the Clang Static Analyzer will warn you about the potential use of uninitialized variables, helping to point out these potential bugs.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant All global variables have static storange duration (or have I missed something?).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe or maybe I am missing something… let me check the standard!

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable without initialization, the OS will allocate memory randomly and at that instant allocated memory may contain some garbage value. That garbage can represent No also or may be Yes value.

Recommended: Always declare a variable with proper initialization to avoid bugs in your code.